# Dynamic InputField on VisualForce Page

Tags: visualforce

Can someone help with the codes to add additional inputfield on VF page if needed.   Just to keep it simple, I have Inputfield asking for user to enter Application1 into my Custom Object A.  But if the user has a second application2 to enter to the same object I would like a button to create a second line and then the user can press save and both lines (Application1 and Application2) will be saved to Object A.

So, a user can enter 1 to n lines and then save to object A.

Thanks for the helps in advance.

Comment: Hi Caky, what have you tried so far? SFSE is a place to receive assistance with issues you might be having, not a place to have others write your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a wrapper class for the object and list of that wrapper in controller, on VF page add one button which will create a blank wrapper instance(that is new row) and then refresh the page that will show new blank row.

One more button to insert records from that list of wrapper to database.